# Qt: Return in main from button_click

Tags: c++, qt, module, qt4, buttonclick

As you can find (if you look at few of mine previous questions) I am pretty new with Qt. I am making "read-from-excel-file-push-to-some-DB" module.

I want to get path wich push button returns in  `main.cpp`

So, long story short here's my code:

fb_test.h

```
#ifndef FB_TEST_H
#define FB_TEST_H

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_fb_test.h"

class FB_test : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    FB_test(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~FB_test();

private:
    Ui::FB_testClass ui;

public slots:
    QString on_pushButton_clicked();

};

#endif // FB_TEST_H
```

fb_test.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "fb_test.h"

FB_test::FB_test(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

}

FB_test::~FB_test()
{

}

QString FB_test::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString path;

    path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
        this,
        "Choose a file to open",
        QString::null,
        QString::null);

    return path;
}
```

main.cpp

```
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QtGui>
    #include <QtSql>
    #include <QAxObject>
    #include <QAxWidget>
    #include "fb_test.h"

    bool initExcel(QAxObject* &excelApp);
    void getTableHeaders(QAxObject* _worksheet, QAxObject*  _excel);
    bool readExcelFile(QAxObject* excel, QString& file_path, QString& selected_list);
    void getTableHeaders(QAxObject* _worksheet, QAxObject*  _excel);

    //....
    //here's methods above implementation 
    //....
    void excelTest(){
        QAxObject* excel;

        QString path = QString("C:\\databases\\oilnstuff.xls");//gonna use GUI choose
        QString list = QString("list1");

        if(initExcel(excel)){
            if (readExcelFile(excel, path, list)){
                //
            }else{
                //error output
            }
        }

        excel->dynamicCall("Quit");
        delete excel;
    }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QComboBox myCombo;

    FB_test *test = new FB_test;
    test->show();


    excelTest();

    return app.exec();
}
```

so here, instead of such right part
`QString path = QString("C:\\databases\\oilnstuff.xls");`

I want to get what `QString FB_test::on_pushButton_clicked()` returns.

How to make such thing?

UPD:
well, such way not works

```
QString mypath = test->ui.pushButton();
```

P.S.

Oh and btw, I am not sure about the way I degin this module.
Maybe I should move all working stuff from `main.cpp` into `FB_test.cpp` and get what button returns there and only call `show()` in `main.cpp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could emit a signal, that a new path was selected and connect it to another component's slot for loading this file. With this, you can get a [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) between classes.

Signals are like:"Hey, something has happended. But I don't matter about who cares about that".

Slots are like: "I do that work, but I don't care about who wants me to do that".

fb_test.h

```
class FB_test : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    FB_test(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~FB_test();

signals:
    void newPathSelected(const QString& path);

private:
    Ui::FB_testClass ui;

public slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

};
```

fb_test.cpp

```
// ...
void FB_test::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString path;

    path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
        this,
        "Choose a file to open",
        QString::null,
        QString::null);

    if (!path.isEmpty())
        emit newPathSelected(path);
}
```

An an excel class could look like this:

```
class MyExcelClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyExcelClass(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyExcelClass();

public slots:
    void readExcelSheet(const QString& path);
};
```

If you have instances of both classes in your main.cpp, this file would look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    FB_test fbTest;

    MyExcelClass *excelClass = new MyExcelClass(&fbTest);  


    connect(&fbTest, SIGNAL(newPathSelected(QString)),
            excelClass, SLOT(readExcelSheet(QString));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Note that fbTest in main isn't dynamically allocated with new because this will result in a memory leak when main finishes. The `excelClass` object will get a pointer to the fbTest object in its constructor, this will ensure, that `excelClass` will get deleted as child object of `fbTest`.

If both the signal and the slot would be in the same class, you have to connect these in the constructor like this:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(newPathSelected(QString)),
            this, SLOT(readExcelSheet(QString));
```

Comment: thanks, cool answer! :3 but is it neccesery to made class? I mean could I use just what inside `FB_test` or it not works that way?

Comment: Yes, this slot can be in the same class. I've edited my anwer.